# Where are all the Magento 1 patches since new Magento.com website?

Tags: patches

I see https://magento.com/download has a new design and content. This used to be the place to find Magento 1 Patches. Where are they now? Everything from Magento 1 seems to be hidden (removed?). Does this have to do with EOL status?

I assume there is a place to find the patches and all the information for Magento 1, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it from the GitHub https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches.

Magento will not support the M1.

Thanks

Comment: So that means there is no official place for these downloads? How would we know the patches on this github are 100% the same as the old Magento.com site?